# To check if lists contain same data

Tags: java, arrays, list, data-structures

I have a list of arrays of objects....Each array has 4 object in it.

I need to read complete list and put all the arrays which have same value at element[1] in seperate lists.

How to do it?

for instance I have a list 'data'

which has nth number of arrays of objects like

```
array[0]
array[1]
array[2]
⋮ 
array[n]
```

each array has 4 values

```
array[0] has 0,23,BD,100
array[1] has 1,23,FG,200
array[2] has 3,34,GH,400
array[3] has 8,87,UJ,600
⋮ 
array[n] has 98,23,KM,9000
```

now I need to put `array[0], array[1] and array[n]` in same `list(List1)` because they all have same value of `'element 2' i-e '23'`

while `array[2]` in a seperate `list(List2)` and `array[3]` in a seperate `list(List3)`because there is no other array that have similar 'element 2' as of them.

All arrays are Object type.

Comment: Why not are you using `utility` classes of java like `ArrayList` or any other ?

Comment: I don't know whats the problem here, a very crappy way to do this would be, take out one object from the list, then iterate over the list comparing the values against the one you took out, then add that object to the correspondent list, and repeat until the original list is empty

Comment: Vishal I don't have any idea , I have never used List before.

Comment: So, long story short, you need to turn a list of arrays into multiple lists based on the second value? Why are you handling this structure on the first place? can you modify the original list to avoid this overhead? If you're going to turn a list of arrays into multple lists of filtered objects can you handle the possibility of changing your first structure?.

Comment: @anakata yes I know this is one way to do it, but I want to know if there is any clean and easy way to do it using any utility classes.

Comment: @Gamb is right, the separation of the list could done in the place where you fill the list

Comment: @Gamb Yes I can try to change first structure but how? could you please give any example? ... As I mentioned before I am first time using List so I dont have much understanding

Comment: This list have already been fill with db values when I get it.

Comment: You get a list of `Object` arrays from database? Are you, by any chance, doing a SELECT and getting a certain number of atributes instead of * or the entity itself (if you're using JPA)? (as in `SELECT e.id, e.name, e.attribute1, e.attribute2 FROM Entity e WHERE SOME_CONDITIONS_HERE`)

Comment: Yes I am getting certain number of attributes all are of different types... coming from different tables using join.

Answer (score 1):

I figured that you were getting the values like this because you were selecting a subset of attributes from one or more tables. Indeed, you end up with a list of arrays of type `Object`. This is because each attribute has its own type so the common supertype that can handle such an undefined situation is `Object` itself.

There are two approaches you can take here. One will require an enhanced interaction with the database and the other one will replace this query tuning with additional processing to prepare the data you just retrieved.

**Option 1: Parametrize your query a little further**

Add another condition to your query, where you define that second attribute (`element 2` as you named it). The query will then have this extra condition:

```
AND element2 = :element2
```

This way, you can determine `element 2` when querying for the data, obtaining each subset of related data directly. This approach will require a previous knowledge of the values you want to retrieve and as much queries as values.

The values can be retrieved with a simple query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(element2) FROM <YOUR_TABLES_HERE>
```

Each time you execute the query, you'll still obtain a `List` of `Object[]` but this time, they'll all have the same value for `element 2`.

**Option 2: Process the data you just obtained**

If changing your query is not an option (or if by any reason there's not a simple way of knowhing the different values `element 2` can take) you will have to process the raw data you just obtained from the database.

I recommend you mix a `Map` with some `List`s. Assuming `element 2` is located under the index `1` of your arrays, you'll have to iterate over that list, check the value and add it to a map:

```
Map<Long, List<Object[]>> queriedResultsMap = new HashMap<Long,List<Object[]>>();
//Iterate over the obtaines database values
for(Object[] currentArray : yourListOfObject) {
    if(!queriedResultsMap.containsKey(currentArray[1])) {
        //No element with that value for "element 2" is on the map yet,
        //so a new container (List) is created.
        queriedResultsMap.put(currentArray[1],new ArrayList<Object[]>());
    }
    //Adds the element to the associated list.
    queriedResultsMap.get(currentArray[1]).add(currentArray);
}
```

This simple piece of code iterates over your current list of arrays and adds each one of them to the list associated to the valye of `element 2` which is the key of the map. In this map, the key is the value of `element 2` and the associated value is a `List` containing all the found registries that have the corresponding value set for `element 2`.

The `if` statement creates a new list each time you encounter a new value for `element 2` and associates it to that value.

Finally, to use the data, you just do this:

```
queriedResultsMap.get(element2Value);
```

Where `element2Value` contains the value you want to get the results for. The list returned by the map contains all of the results that have the particular value of `element 2`. If no list is returned (the `get` method returns `null`) you know that the query you just ran returned no results for that value of `element 2`.

The map allows a direct association between each found value for `element 2` and also gives you a direct insight of all the obtained values while giving you the chance to instantly check if a particular value was retrieved. To know exactly which values of `element 2` were found just obtain the `keySet` of your map and to know if a given value was retrieved use the `containsKey` method of the `Map`.

Use whichever approach suits you best.